# cakephp not validating select field

Tags: validation, cakephp

I just downloaded a fresh copy of cakephp version 2.3.0 and I am trying to validate a select field of a form that I have just created:

```
echo $this->Form->input('province_id', array('empty' => '- select -', 'options' => $options));
echo $this->Form->input('username');
```

And the validation:

```
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A username is required'
        )
    ),

    'province_id' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Select something'
    )
);
```

The username field is being validated correctly, but the province_id is being ignored. What can it be?

Answer (score 2):

You should write like this:

```
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A username is required'
        )
    ),
    'province_id' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Select something'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your form helper declarations are fine.

My experience with Cake shows that the validation is screwy when you start to mix the syntax (one of your fields has a nested array, while the other doesn't). I am sure there is some rhyme or reason to what is going on, but I haven't really dived that deep and usually just do trial and error.

Try this:

```
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'A username is required'
    ),

    'province_id' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'Select something'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better late then never, try this:

```
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A username is required'
        )
    ),
    'province_id' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('myOwnValidationRule'),
            'message' => 'Select something'
        )
    )
);

function myOwnValidationRule($data)
{ 
    if($data["province_id"] != 'empty')
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```